# I'm trying to make a 2.2 Amplifier, is my schematic correct or suggest any improvement?

Tags: amplifier, audio

This is my project schematic, I'm using TDA2050, and the input voltage is ±12V.
Is it correct or does it need any improvement?

[image: Schematic]

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is a "2.2 Amplifier"? Where did you hear the term? (I never have.) It looks to me to be a "bridge-mode" amplifier. The input / feedback arrangement on the right is unusual.

Comment: @Transistor That’s the channel configuration, 2 speakers, 2 subwoofers. You might have seen the term 5.1 audio, that one is pretty common, 5 speakers, left front and back, right front and back, center, and 1 subwoofer.

Comment: Can you explain how the amplifier should work in order to know if it works as you expect or not? Are you trying to make a bridged output?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that for the basic design of a component, adherence to the specifications provided in the datasheet is essential. Specifically for IC design, following the placement guidelines for bypass capacitors as depicted in the image below is imperative.

Picture reference: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000131.pdf

[image: Datasheet picture]
[image]

Ensure these capacitors are positioned close to the IC Pad for optimal performance.
In relation to the rest of the design, you should provide more details